# How to do instrumentation test on Android default browser?

Tags: android

Here is my condition:

- Purpose: Do instrumentation or JUnit test on Android default browser.
- I use Eclipse to develop test program.

Since it cannot build browser source code in Eclipse, so cannot control any component by using `findViewByID()`.

How could I control browser's component then do some test, such as update URL, reload page, search by google, etc?

Thx & B.R

Leo

Comment: Add a comment that I use Robotium library to develop my program.

Answer (score 0):

there is a a selenium androiddriver for that purpose, see:
[AndrodiDriver-Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver)